# Error en aplicacion de laravel con sql server en windows

Tags: sql-server, laravel, xampp

he configurado el xampp v3.2.2 con sql srv, tengo una aplicación laravel 5.5 configurada para conectarse al sql server de la siguiente manera:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:SFla+HfV2OBTy/KYCrSZeBbwGWMUfZBKrnKwNzJrfQU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://app.develop

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=IP
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=BD
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=pass
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
...
```

al iniciar la aplicacion a penas solicito alguna consulta me aparece el siguiente error:

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (IMSSP)
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object. (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] where [email] = email)
```

La misma aplicacion funciona sin problema en ubuntu 17 y 18...

He bajado los drivers de sql server suministrados por microsoft he inclui las siguientes lineas en las extensiones del php.ini

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
```

y las librerias en la carpeta de ext de php....

Comment: agrega el código de la consulta que estas tratando

Comment: La consulta que se ejecuta esta en el error, se ejecuta automaticamente a traves del modulo auth que se activa en laravel

Answer (score 1):

me respondo, he encontrado la raiz del problema, simplemente hay que descomentar un atributo en la conexión de laravel en el fichero approot/config/database.php

En este se encuentran las conexiones para las BD donde el sistema se comunicara, para sql server tenia la siguiente definicion:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 300000,
            ],
        ],
```

removi el atributo options, quedando como sigue

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            /*'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 300000,
            ],*/
        ],
```

y listo el sistema autentica, y muestra ldos datos....